# Help with some json data and php

Tags: php, json

I just need a little help with json and php. How do i echo certian parts of data if my request comes back looking like this:

```
{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "2", "humidity": "54", "observation_time": "09:05 PM", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1019", "temp_C": "11", "visibility": "10", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Clear" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "N", "winddirDegree": "350", "windspeedKmph": "15", "windspeedMiles": "9" } ],  "request": [ {"query": "48.85,2.35", "type": "LatLon" } ] }}
```

I am using a weather API, my code currently looks like:

```
$weather_url = file_get_contents("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=xxxxx&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$json_output_w = json_decode($weather_url, true);
```

the q in the url string can be a zipcode, lat and long, or a city, i know it is returning data because i can dump the variable $json_output_w; but i just need a little guidance as how to actually echo certain parts of the data that is returned. like say i wanted to echo
 `windspeedMiles`

Comment: `var_dump($json_output_w);` ?

Comment: i don't want to display all of the data, i am just looking for some helo with displaying certain information that in that array of data, like               echo $json_output_w['data']['current_condition']['cloudcover'];      but that doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: if that doesn't return anything - then either there is nothing in that item or you're trying to retrieve a key that doesn't exist. So you still need `var_dump()` to inspect your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function will return either an object or array (depending on the second argument). You can explore the structure of the returned item using the `var_dump()` function:

```
var_dump( $json_output_w );
```

From here you would discover what type of structure you need to consider when pulling values out. To get the `windSpeedMiles` value, you'd do the following:

```
echo $json_output_w["data"]["current_condition"][0]["windspeedMiles"];
```

Online Demo: http://codepad.org/BfhHbQMz